# How to build a Custom Data Generator for Keras/tf.Keras where X images are being augmented and corresponding Y labels are also images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am working on Image Binarization using UNet and have a dataset of 150 images and their binarized versions too. My idea is to augment the images randomly to make them look like they are differentso I have made a function which inserts any of the 4-5 types of Noises, skewness, shearing and so on to an image. I could have easily used

`ImageDataGenerator(preprocess_function=my_aug_function)` to augment the images but the problem is that my **y target** is also an image. Also, I could have used something like:

```
train_dataset = (
    train_dataset.map(
        encode_single_sample, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    )
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
)
```

But it has 2 problems:

1. With larger dataset, it'll blow up the memory as data needs to be already in the memory
2. This is the crucial part that I need to augment the images on the go to make it look like I have a huge dataset.

Another Solution could be saving augmented images to a directory and making them 30-40K and then loading them. It would be silly thing to do.

Now the idea part is that I can use `Sequence` as the parent class but How can I keep on augmenting and generating new images on the fly with respective Y binarized images?

I have an idea as the below code. Can somebody help me with the augmentation and generation of y images. I have my `X_DIR, Y_DIR` where image names for binarised and original are same but stored in different directories.

```
class DataGenerator(tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, files_path, labels_path, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, random_state=42):
        'Initialization'
        self.files = files_path
        self.labels = labels_path
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.random_state = random_state
        self.on_epoch_end()


    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        # Shuffle the data here


    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(len(self.files) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # What do I do here? 


    def __data_generation(self, files):
        # I think this is responsible for Augmentation but no idea how should I implement it and how does it works.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Custom Image Data Generator

### load Directory data into dataframe for CustomDataGenerator

```py
def data_to_df(data_dir, subset=None, validation_split=None):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    filenames = []
    labels = []
    
    for dataset in os.listdir(data_dir):
        img_list = os.listdir(os.path.join(data_dir, dataset))
        label = name_to_idx[dataset]
        
        for image in img_list:
            filenames.append(os.path.join(data_dir, dataset, image))
            labels.append(label)
        
    df["filenames"] = filenames
    df["labels"] = labels
    
    if subset == "train":
        split_indexes = int(len(df) * validation_split)
        train_df = df[split_indexes:]
        val_df = df[:split_indexes]
        return train_df, val_df
    
    return df

train_df, val_df = data_to_df(train_dir, subset="train", validation_split=0.2)
```

### Custom Data Generator

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

class CustomDataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    ''' Custom DataGenerator to load img 
    
    Arguments:
        data_frame = pandas data frame in filenames and labels format
        batch_size = divide data in batches
        shuffle = shuffle data before loading
        img_shape = image shape in (h, w, d) format
        augmentation = data augmentation to make model rebust to overfitting
    
    Output:
        Img: numpy array of image
        label : output label for image
    '''
    
    def __init__(self, data_frame, batch_size=10, img_shape=None, augmentation=True, num_classes=None):
        self.data_frame = data_frame
        self.train_len = len(data_frame)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.img_shape = img_shape
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        print(f"Found {self.data_frame.shape[0]} images belonging to {self.num_classes} classes")

    def __len__(self):
        ''' return total number of batches '''
        self.data_frame = shuffle(self.data_frame)
        return math.ceil(self.train_len/self.batch_size)

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        ''' shuffle data after every epoch '''
        # fix on epoch end it's not working, adding shuffle in len for alternative
        pass
    
    def __data_augmentation(self, img):
        ''' function for apply some data augmentation '''
        img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_shift(img, 0.2, 0.3)
        img = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(img)
        img = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(img)
        return img
        
    def __get_image(self, file_id):
        """ open image with file_id path and apply data augmentation """
        img = np.asarray(Image.open(file_id))
        img = np.resize(img, self.img_shape)
        img = self.__data_augmentation(img)
        img = preprocess_input(img)

        return img

    def __get_label(self, label_id):
        """ uncomment the below line to convert label into categorical format """
        #label_id = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(label_id, num_classes)
        return label_id

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.data_frame["filenames"][idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.data_frame["labels"][idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        # read your data here using the batch lists, batch_x and batch_y
        x = [self.__get_image(file_id) for file_id in batch_x] 
        y = [self.__get_label(label_id) for label_id in batch_y]

        return tf.convert_to_tensor(x), tf.convert_to_tensor(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like albumentations and imgaug, both are good but I have heard there are issues with random seed with albumentations.
Here's an example of imgaug taken from the documentation [here](https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/examples_segmentation_maps.html):

```
seq = iaa.Sequential([
    iaa.Dropout([0.05, 0.2]),      # drop 5% or 20% of all pixels
    iaa.Sharpen((0.0, 1.0)),       # sharpen the image
    iaa.Affine(rotate=(-45, 45)),  # rotate by -45 to 45 degrees (affects segmaps)
    iaa.ElasticTransformation(alpha=50, sigma=5)  # apply water effect (affects segmaps)
], random_order=True)

# Augment images and segmaps.
images_aug = []
segmaps_aug = []
for _ in range(len(input_data)):
    images_aug_i, segmaps_aug_i = seq(image=image, segmentation_maps=segmap)
    images_aug.append(images_aug_i)
    segmaps_aug.append(segmaps_aug_i)
```

You are going in the right way with the custom generator. In `__getitem__`, make a batch using `batch_x = self.files[index:index+batch_size]` and same with `batch_y`, then augment them using `X,y = __data_generation(batch_x, batch_y)` which will load images(using any library you like, I prefer opencv), and return the augmented pairs (and any other manipulation).

Your `__getitem__` will then return the tuple `(X,y)`

Comment: But there is no documentation given on `__data_generation`. I mean How is it supposed to be giving me infinite images from 150?

Comment: `__data_generation` is not a necessary function as far as I know (if it is, I suggest you don't use it unless you are sure you should override it). You can use any function to generate your data and call it by any name from `__getitem__`. Infinite images are not generated by that function(or any function), it's just 150 images being augmented differently each epoch, but, same images nonetheless. Generator helps you load some images (your batch size) and then augment them and forget them the next epoch.

Comment: Yeah I know but I am unable to get the idea of how it'll go for when it iterates the fulll 150 say in 15 iterqtions with batch size =10? Could you please write a code to get the respective Iamges from DIR assuming your own params. Once I get the idea of how it can be done, I can modify the `__data_generation`

Comment: It will repeat the same 150 samples, however many times you want. You don't have to take care of that, the parent class has something that does that for you (unless the repetition is handled by `__data_generation` internally. I am not sure. If it is not documented and you can't make sure from the source, just name your function something else)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageDataGenerator even if your label is an image.
Here is a simple example of how you can do that:

**Code:**

```
# Specifying your data augmentation here for both image and label
image_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
mask_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()

# Provide the same seed and keyword arguments to the flow methods
seed = 1
image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed)
mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed)

# Combine the image and label generator.
train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)
```

Now, if you iterate over it you will get:

```
for image, label in train_generator:
  print(image.shape,label.shape)
  break
```

**Output:**

```
(32, 256, 256, 3) (32, 256, 256, 3)
```

You can use this train_generator with `fit()` command.

**Code:**

```
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2000,
    epochs=50)
```

With `flow_from_directory` your memory won't be cluttered and `Imagedatagenerator` will take care of the augmentation part.