# How to get the next iteration when zipping two iterables

Tags: python, iterable

I need to train a model when the label themselves are images. I want to apply the same data augmentations to both the input image and the output image. following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63829416/5650267), I have zipped two generators:

```
# create augmentation generators for the input images and label images
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=45, width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, brightness_range=(0.5,1.5),
                                               fill_mode="reflect", horizontal_flip=True ,zoom_range=0.3,preprocessing_function = self.apply_kernels)
desity_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=45, width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, brightness_range=(0.5,1.5),
                                               fill_mode="reflect", horizontal_flip=True ,zoom_range=0.3,preprocessing_function = self.apply_kernels)
image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(self.train_data_dir, batch_size=batch_size, class_mode=None, seed=seed)
density_generator = desity_datagen.flow_from_directory(self.train_label_dir, batch_size=batch_size, class_mode=None, seed=seed)
# Combine the image and label generator
self.train_generator = zip(image_generator, density_generator)
```

I have built it inside a generator calss which I initialize using:

```
gen = data_generator(path_to_images, path_to_labels, batch_size);
```

I am not including the whole class because I am not sure it is required. I will edit and add it if needed. I am trying to call the next batch from both generators to see if it works:

```
image,label = gen.train_generator.next()
print(labels.shape)
```

And I get

> AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute 'next'

I understand why I get it, though I don't know how to get a single batch.

Using `list(gen.train_generator)` is too big for memory.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, `zip()` is already an iterator.

Comment: @havakok, you're getting first pair returned by zip, isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: @havakok, you want to consume both generators? Maybe `list(gen.train_generator)` is what you're searching.

Comment: I think you meant to put the print in a for loop: `for image, label in gen.train_generator:` It gets a single batch every time and you can stop going further at any time with `break`. Manually calling `gen.train_generator.__next__()` directly isn't something you'd usually do. (unless there's something special about the first iteration, and you want to get rid of it leaving the rest)

Comment: No @OlvinRoght, I am working with very large data and it won't fit on memory if I use `list(gen.train_generator)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
gen.train_generator.__next__()
```

although @OlvinRoght's comment/answer is cleaner.

Comment: Which comment/answer do you mean?

Comment: One that has (apparently) been deleted.

Comment: touching `__whatever__` should be a good indication that you're doing it wrong

Answer (score 2):

You should use the built-in function, [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) -

```py
value = next(gen.train_generator)
```

`next` will throw a `StopIteration` exception if there is no next value. Make sure to wrap in `try-except` to prevent errors from bubbling up -

```py
try:
  value = next(gen.train_generator)
except StopIteration:
  value = None
```

Because this pattern is so common, `next` accepts a secondary argument to use in the event the generator is exhausted -

```py
value = next(gen.train_generator, None) # default to None if generator is exhausted
```